# Meta-analysis of binary outcome data where both arms have 100% events

Tags: meta-analysis

I am running a meta analysis of events between two different groups.
In one paper the event rate is 100% in both groups and no box is generated.
I'm aware that Cochrane recommends excluding papers where there is 0 events in both arms - is it the same case for those with 100% in both arms

I've used the metabin package in R (happy to supply other details if required)

thanks in advance
Kyle

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem.